# ssh login works only over local network after upgrading to 22.04.1. Keep getting "permission denied" when I try away from local network

Tags: server, ssh

Everything worked fine(ssh) until I finally decided to do the upgrade from 20.04.1 because I was tired of seeing the "do-upgrade" message everytime I was logging in my server. So after the upgrade I was able to log in my headless server over my local network(home) and still to this day but when I try to log in from my office (away from home) I always get permission denied (publickey,password) like my password was not the good one but I use the very same password I use at home to log in. I plugged a monitor on the server, enabled remote ssh connection and remote desktop sharing and still doesnt work away from home. At this point I searched for about 3-4 days googling messing with sshd_config trying to see if somehow the new Ubuntu/openssh was blocking IP'S from outside my home network (UFW is disabled and yes my router is set to forward the port 22 to my server as it was before the upgrade to 22.04.1). I tried purging openssh-server, reinstall it but still it works only over my local network. Hope someone will come with some "fresh air" over this annoying issue.

```
dux@MacBook-Pro-de-duX ~ %  ssh -vvv dux@184.14*.***.**
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/dux/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include 
/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 184.14*.***.** is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 
'/Users/dux/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 
'/Users/dux/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; 
disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 184.14*.***.*** [184.144.***.**] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dux/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 
dropbear_2018.76
debug1: compat_banner: no match: dropbear_2018.76
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 184.14*.***.**:22 as 'dux'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file 
/Users/dux/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from 184.14*.***.**
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/dux/.ssh/known_hosts2: No 
such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such 
file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such 
file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert- 
v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2- 
512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519- 
sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519- 
sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh- 
sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie- 
hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie- 
hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert- 
v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2- 
512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa- 
sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert- 
v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh- 
ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2- 
nistp521
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128- 
ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256- 
gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128- 
ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256- 
gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128- 
etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512- 
etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac- 
64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2- 
512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128- 
etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512- 
etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac- 
64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2- 
512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519- 
sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh- 
sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14- 
sha256,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes256- 
cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes256- 
cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 
compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 
compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa 
SHA256:uGq/Tt6huITf4zqqV3SIIxd8MH1QGcQtahSYGCskpxg
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file 
/Users/dux/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from 184.14*.***.**
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/dux/.ssh/known_hosts2: No 
such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such 
file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such 
file or directory. 
debug1: Host '184.144.***.**' is known and matches the RSA host 
key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/dux/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS.  
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent 
contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
SHA256:NDtstCom+vwC4hyw9UQIy6HOiS5lM9tqfs9mO5hTz58
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
SHA256:NDtstCom+vwC4hyw9UQIy6HOiS5lM9tqfs9mO5hTz58
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file 
or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk. 
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such 
file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such 
file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such 
file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file 
or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dux/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or 
directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
dux@184.14*.***.**'s password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
dux@184.14*.***.**'s password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
dux@184.14*.***.**'s password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
dux@184.144.***.**: Permission denied (publickey,password).
dux@MacBook-Pro-de-duX ~ %
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142772/discussion-on-question-by-duxx-ssh-login-works-only-over-local-network-after-upg); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.